# On the integrals of two complex valued functions which get closer

Tags: integration

Suppose $f,g$ are complex valued continuous functions defined on positive real axis.  Suppose for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $M$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x>M$ and it is given that $\left|\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\right|<c_1<\infty$.  Is it then true that $|\int_0^\infty g(x)dx|<c_2<\infty$ for some constant $c_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is no because consider for instance $g(x)=f(x)+1/x$.  Then given $\epsilon>0$ there is $M$ such that $1/x<\epsilon$ for sure.  But $|\int_0^\infty g(x)dx|$ is not finite.